# What does lowercase "month" mean in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, datetime

I found a very strange problem in Scala. I was trying to get the last day of last month. The following worksheet showed the correct result (in Scala, Month starts from 0(Jan), so Mar. is 2).

[image]

However, if I comment out the last line on the left, the results are as the follows:

[image]

What I did is just to assign the `lastMonth` variable to `month`. And the `lastMonth` is changed to 3!

Where did I do wrong?

Here is the code snippet:

```
import java.util.{Calendar, GregorianCalendar} // Get current time and the last date of last month

val now = Calendar.getInstance()
// test code
//now.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER)

// get current year
val currYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR)
// get current month, JANUARY is 0
val currMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH)

// back to last month
val lastMonthCalendar = now
// if this month is Dec, the YEAR would be automatically deducted by 1
lastMonthCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1)
lastMonthCalendar.getTime
val lastMonth = lastMonthCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val numDaysOfLastMonth = lastMonthCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
lastMonthCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, numDaysOfLastMonth)
lastMonthCalendar.getTime

var year = lastMonthCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
var month = lastMonth
```

Comment: Well, `lastMonth` is April = 4-1 = 3... What's the problem?

Comment: You should be using `LocalDate` rather than `Calendar` anyway

Comment: No, April is 3 in Calendar. `lastMonth` should be 2

Comment: `Calendar.APRIL` is 3. `calendarInstance.get(Calendar.MONTH)` will be 4.

Comment: Yes `LocalDate` works but why doesn't `Calendar` work?

Comment: But the only difference between these two parts is the final line. I just assinged a value to a variable...

Comment: lastMonth and month are always the same value... And it'll be 3 because it's March, the third month... It will **not** be two. I don't understand what you looking for, but please accept my answer below if that's what you want in the code

Comment: For those of us with old eyes who have forgot our glasses, could you sum up in text what the images show, please?

Comment: This is not reproducible. I get 2 for both variables.

Comment: @cricket_007 In Calendar class, MONTH starts from 0. JANUARY is 0 so MARCH is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get the last day of last month

Is this what you want?

```
scala> import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDate

scala>  LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1)
res1: java.time.LocalDate = 2018-03-31

scala> res1.getDayOfMonth
res2: Int = 31

scala> res1.getMonth
res3: java.time.Month = MARCH

scala> res1.getMonthValue
res4: Int = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! `LocalDate` is really useful!